# Combine Data from Multiple tables SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello I have 3 Tables in Database `Customer`, `Payment` and `Refund`. Structure is as below:

Customer Table:

| CustId | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hi |
| 2 | hello |
| 3 | gg |
| 4 | hh |

Payment Table:

| pmtId | custId | PmtNotes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | kk |
| 11 | 2 | pp |
| 12 | 3 | NULL |
| 15 | 4 | dd |

Refund Table:

| refId | custId | refNotes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 1 | ww |
| 34 | 2 | mm |
| 35 | 3 | jj |
| 65 | 2 | ii |

Expected Result:

| CustId | Notes | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | gg | 1 |
| 3 | JJ | 3 |

col1 = 1: Because this data is from Customer table.

col1 = 3: Because this data is from Refund table.

I want this type of result based on the customer id, I found similar questions but I can't find the most relevant solution for this.
Any help would be appreciated as I am quite a beginner in SQL server.

Comment: So what have you tried? Why didn't it work? Seems like a `JOIN` and unpivot perhaps?

Comment: Please clarify the logic behind expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to select customer with notes from different tables along with the indication of which table the data belongs to. I have considered rows only with non null notes. Please check.

First I have union all rows from three tables where notes column is not null and added an extra column to indicate table from which that row has come.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Customer (CustId   int, Notes  varchar(50));          
 insert into Customer 
 values
 (1        , 'hi'     ),           
 (2        , 'hello'  ),            
 (3        , 'gg'     ),            
 (4        , 'hh'     );            
      
 create table Payment (pmtId int, custId int ,PmtNotes varchar(50));         
 insert into Payment  values
 (10    ,1     , 'kk'),       
 (11    ,2     , 'pp'),               
 (12    ,3     , NULL),             
 (15    ,4     , 'dd');               
 
 create table Refund (refId int, custId int, refNotes varchar(50));
 insert into Refund values
 (33    ,1      ,  'ww'),
 (34    ,2      ,  'mm'), 
 (35    ,3      ,  'jj'),
 (65    ,2      ,  'ii');
```

Query:

```
 select * from 
 (
     select custid, notes, 1 Col1 from customer where notes is not null
     union all
     select custid, PmtNotes, 2 Col1 from Payment where PmtNotes is not null
     union all
     select custid, refNotes, 3 Col1 from Refund where refNotes is not null
 )t where custid=3
```

Output:

| custid | notes | Col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | gg | 1 |
| 3 | jj | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f33700669d584aa54a4ae62be7bff816)*

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
 SELECT * FROM Customer
    LEFT JOIN payment
    ON customer.CustId = Payment.custId
    LEFT JOIN Refund
    ON customer.CustId = Refund.CustId
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
   LEFT JOIN payment
   ON customer.CustId = Payment.custId
   LEFT JOIN Refund
   ON customer.CustId = Refund.CustId
WHERE Customer.CustId = 2
```

Add the WHERE Clause to filter to a single customer or remove all entries. A Left Join will bring empty cols too.

Answer (score 0):

This *seems* to be what you are after; just a couple of `JOIN`s and an unpivot:

```sql
SELECT C.CustID,
       V.Notes,
       V.Col1
FROM dbo.Customer C
     JOIN dbo.Payment P ON C.CustID = P.CustID --Might need to be a LEFT JOIN
     JOIN dbo.Refund R ON C.CustID = R.CustID --Might need to be a LEFT JOIN
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(C.Notes,1),
                       (P.PmtNotes,2),
                       (R.RefNotes,3))V(Notes,Col1)
WHERE C.CustID = 3
  AND V.Notes IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I exactly tried this approach earlier with ```Left``` join, Got same Entry multiple times.

Comment: it won't for the example you have given us, @MaulikDave . And if you *tried* this approach **why** isn't it in your question..?

Comment: @Larmu sincere apologies, but yes I only could demonstrate with the little piece of data, i will create and sqlFiddle example and will post a new question.

Comment: @Larmu I am sharing sql fiddle demo if you can look into it. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e141f6/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e141f6/1)